# Can't import graph dump on neo4j 3.5.28 on RHEL 8.4

Tags: neo4j, redhat

I have a fresh install of RHEL 8.4 running neo4j 3.5.28, and when I attempt to run `neo4j-admin load --from=<file>` I get the following error:

```
Unsupported OS/arch, cannot find /linux/amd64/libzstd-jni.so or load zstd-jni from system libraries. Please try building from source the jar or providing libzstd-jni in you system.
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124)
    at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native.load(Native.java:108)
    at com.github.luben.zstd.util.Native.load(Native.java:60)
    at com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdInputStream.<clinit>(ZstdInputStream.java:21)
    at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.CompressionFormat$2.decompress(CompressionFormat.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.Loader.openArchiveIn(Loader.java:151)
    at org.neo4j.dbms.archive.Loader.load(Loader.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.LoadCommand.load(LoadCommand.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.LoadCommand.execute(LoadCommand.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:127)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:51)
```

I've been able to replicate this across multiple fresh servers, but not on centos 8 oddly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our admin had the /var/tmp and /tmp directories set to have the noexec flag. Removing this flag allowed the import to work without a problem.